# LibGit2Sharp - Merge develop in master branch

Tags: libgit2sharp

I want to merge my develop in my master branch with LibGit2Sharp, but I can't find any examples on the [GitHub wiki of LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp).
How can I do that?

Code snippet:

```
using (var repo = new Repository(repoDirectory))
{
    var masterBranch = repo.Branches["master"];
    var developBranch = repo.Branches["develop"];

    Commands.Checkout(repo, masterBranch);
    // merge dev in master
    // tag master
    Commands.Checkout(repo, developBranch);
    // merge master in dev
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I'm not sure if it could be done in another way, but I works.

```
using (var repo = new Repository(repoDirectory))
{
    var masterBranch = repo.Branches["master"];
    var developBranch = repo.Branches["develop"];
    var merger = new Signature(AuthorName, AuthorEmail, DateTime.Now);

    Commands.Checkout(repo, masterBranch);
    repo.Merge(developBranch, merger, new MergeOptions());

    repo.ApplyTag("v0.1");

    Commands.Checkout(repo, developBranch);
    repo.Merge(masterBranch, merger, new MergeOptions());
}
```